# using cordova-plugin-admobpro and cordova-plugin-fcm together

Tags: android, ios, firebase, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

- When i am using `cordova-plugin-admobpro` and `cordova-plugin-fcm` plugins together, i get following build error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

> Execution failed for task `:processDebugGoogleServices`. Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available [here](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.2.0.

i'm using ionic framework and if use add one and then build it works, but together does not.

can somebody help on this please?

Comment: using cordova-plugin-admobpro and cordova-plugin-fcm together

Answer (score 0):

try what i suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40337265/1791529) , download the admob-pro plugin, make the changes as in the link and add the plugin from your local machine, it should work.

Comment: thanks @bmukorera for your suggestion, i have solved this issue by using cordova-plugin-firebase plug in, it worked.

Comment: Thanks @Emirbi will also checkout cordova-plugin-firebase